# Configuring cascade delete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I have 8 objects which reference a generic entity called ExpenseType. There are 36 references to ExpenseType between the 8 objects. I'd like to configure cascade delete so that when the referencing objects are deleted, so too are the ExpenseType records.

I'm using Code First Entity Framework 5 and have already done this for other objects in my schema, but the generic nature of this has me stumped.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
John

```
public class HouseholdExpenses
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int HouseholdExpensesId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Childcare")]
        public virtual ExpenseType Childcare { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Elderly Care (Carer Nursing Home etc)")]
        public virtual ExpenseType ElderlyCare { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Food / Housekeeping / Personal Care")]
        public virtual ExpenseType FoodHousekeeping { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Clothing and Footwear")]
        public virtual ExpenseType ClothingFootwear { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "House Repairs and Maintenance")]
        public virtual ExpenseType RepairsAndMaintenance { get; set; }
}

    public class MedicalExpenses
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int MedicalExpensesId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Medical Expenses and Prescription Charges")]
        public virtual ExpenseType MedicalExpensesAndPrescriptions { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Health Insurance (unless deducted from your salary at source)")]
        public virtual ExpenseType HealthInsurance { get; set; }
}

public class ExpenseType
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ExpenseTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public virtual decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Arrears")]
    public virtual decimal? Arrears { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnModelCreating` and try this. Unless I am forgetting something I think it should work.

```
mBuilder.Entity<ExpenseType>()
            .HasRequired(he => he.Childcare)
            .WithMany();

mBuilder.Entity<ExpenseType>()
            .HasRequired(ec => ec.ElderlyCare)
            .WithMany();
...
```